# Is it possible to fetch foursquare user's history using Facebook id/psw?

Tags: facebook, oauth, foursquare

Suppose that I make an app that is using Facebook login (basically for dealing with who is who). Is it possible that the app to fetch the user's history from Foursquare if it get the user's permission? (The user uses Facebook's login on Foursquare as well)

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to go through each authorization flow separately. First, the user grant your application access by going to Facebook and coming back with an access token (or authorization code you later exchange). Then you need to send them over to Foursquare to approve access again. Foursquare might need to authenticate them via Facebook but that's really not your concern (and should be transparent if they have an active Facebook session). Foursquare will issue you another access token for their API.

There are discussions in the community about the use case of allowing your application to pass the Facebook access token to Foursquare so they can validate the user identity with Facebook and then issue you an access token. However, there are many issues with that. By not directly interacting with the user, Foursquare has no way of knowing that the user wants to give one application access to their data stored on another application.